# How to create SOAP API in Magento 2

Tags: soap, magento2, magento2.4

I've been searching though the whole internet but there's little to none information about how to create custom SOAP endpoints in Magento 2 (specifically 2.4.4). The official documentation only talks about testing and authentication. So I am writing this question to maybe at least get some overall info about how to do it.